# How to select all distinct values in a MySQL subquery into a group_concat?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, substring, group-concat

I'm running `MySQL 5.0.88` and have a search which I'm running a `presearch` to determine `number of records`,. `min-max values` as well as `element strings of distinct values`.

A result of the query will look like this:

```
  records      min-price    max-price   sizeRange   colorRange
  1234         9.00         124.00      S,M,L,XL    red,blue,white,orange
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT    COUNT(recordcount) AS total_records
        , MIN(min_price_ek) AS ek_min
        , MAX(max_price_ek) AS ek_max
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ), ',', 10  ) AS sz_rng
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ), ',', 16  ) AS cl_rng 

        FROM (SELECT  a.id AS recordcount
                    , a.nos
                    , a.nos_anzeige
                    , MAX(<cfif variables.preislisten neq "">IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)<cfelse>a.preis_ek</cfif>) AS max_price_ek
                    , MIN(<cfif variables.preislisten neq "">IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)<cfelse>a.preis_ek</cfif>) AS min_price_ek
                    , a.groesse AS sizeRange
                    , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange

              FROM artikelstammdaten a

              LEFT JOIN farbenzuordnung zu 
                ON a.farbe = zu.farbe 

              WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
          AND a.artikelnummer LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#art#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">

              GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer, a.preis_aktuell, a.artikelbezeichnung
              HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja" ))

        ) AS temp
```

This works ok, but I'm still having trouble with selecting all available sizes/colors. I'm getting some values, but not all.

My table looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE dummy (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `artikelnummer` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `preis_ek` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `preis_vk` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `firma` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `nos` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `nos_anzeige` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `aktiv` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `bestand` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT '0'
  )
```

So an product will be stored in the table with one entry per size like so:

```
 product_id      ean           size     price
 1234          111111111111    S        9.99
 1234          111111111112    M        9.99
 1234          111111111113...
```

From what I'm getting back in MySQL, I think I'm only selecting the first size (`S`) of articles and create a `GROUP_CONCAT of all DISTINCT first sizes` vs a `GROUP_CONCAT` of all DISTINCT sizes of the recordset`.

**Question**: 
Can someone give me a pointer on how I need to tweak my `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Thanks!

**This is the query I'm currently testing with**

```
SELECT    COUNT(recordcount) AS total_records
        , MIN(min_price_ek) AS ek_min
        , MAX(max_price_ek) AS ek_max
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ), ',', 10  ) AS sz_rng
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ), ',', 16  ) AS cl_rng 

        FROM (SELECT  a.id AS recordcount
                    , a.nos
                    , a.nos_anzeige
                    , MAX(a.preis_ek) AS max_price_ek
                    , MIN(a.preis_ek) AS min_price_ek
                    , a.groesse AS sizeRange
                    , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange

                FROM artikelstammdaten a

                LEFT JOIN farbenzuordnung zu 
                    ON a.farbe = zu.farbe 
                WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
                AND a.artikelnummer LIKE "%402%"

                GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer
                HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja" ))

        ) AS temp
```

I have removed the 3rd table (currency lookup/leftjoin), because results are false with or without it. This is the remaining two tables:

```
   ** artikelstammdaten = product data **
   CREATE TABLE dummy (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `iln` VARCHAR(13) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ean` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artikelnummer` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `groesse` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `farbe` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_ek` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_vk` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `preis_aktuell` DECIMAL(12,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `marke` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nos` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nos_anzeige` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `aktiv` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modus` VARCHAR(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bestand` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT '0'
 )

   ** global colors / farbenzuordnung **
   CREATE TABLE dummy (
    `ILN` VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    `farbe` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    `systemfarbe` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    `systemfarbe_en` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL
   )
```

I'm testing with a single product right now (`402`). The product has 4 sizes and two colors, so this is 8 records in the database. Running the query on it should return `s,m,l,xl` for sizes and `red, black` for colors as Group__concat. However I'm only getting (arbitraty?)  `s` and `red` as results.

Still clueless as to why.

Comment: Have you tried by removing substring_index function, i.e. simply using group_concat function?

Comment: hm. Is there another way to limit what is getting put into the GROUP_CONCAT then? If possible, I'd only include the TOP 20 occuring sizes/colors rather than limiting the GROUP_CONCAT to 10/16 results

Comment: On what criteria do you define TOP 20?

Comment: sorry. Most occurrences. So how often size XL is in the resultset for example

Comment: What are a.nos_anzeige and a.nos in your sub-query?

Comment: @shubhansh:  true/false fields, NOS = never out of stock. I only include items with `inventory>0` or `NeverOutofStockItem=true` and `NeverOutofStock_activated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query as follows using [GROUP_CONCAT along with ORDER BY CLAUSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat),

Note: you need to define the criteria in following query based on your requirements

```
SELECT    COUNT(recordcount) AS total_records
        , MIN(min_price_ek) AS ek_min
        , MAX(max_price_ek) AS ek_max
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT sizeRange ORDER BY [criteria]), ',', 20  ) AS sz_rng
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT colorRange ORDER BY [criteria]), ',', 20  ) AS cl_rng 

        FROM (SELECT  a.id AS recordcount
                    , a.nos
                    , a.nos_anzeige
                    , MAX(<cfif variables.preislisten neq "">IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)<cfelse>a.preis_ek</cfif>) AS max_price_ek
                    , MIN(<cfif variables.preislisten neq "">IFNULL(p.ek, a.preis_ek)<cfelse>a.preis_ek</cfif>) AS min_price_ek
                    , a.groesse AS sizeRange
                    , zu.systemfarbe AS colorRange

              FROM artikelstammdaten a

              LEFT JOIN farbenzuordnung zu 
                ON a.farbe = zu.farbe 

              WHERE a.aktiv = "ja"
          AND a.artikelnummer LIKE <cfqueryparam value="#art#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">

              GROUP BY a.iln, a.artikelnummer, a.preis_aktuell, a.artikelbezeichnung
              HAVING (( sum(a.bestand) != 0 ) OR (a.nos = "ja" AND a.nos_anzeige = "ja" ))

        ) AS temp
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Cool. Trying this. Thanks so far!

Comment: hm. MySQL is complaining about `invalid use of GROUP function`

Comment: What are you filling in place of criteria?

Comment: Right now I have `COUNT(sizeRange)`

Comment: No, it will not work!!! ORDER BY clause here is similar to that of ORDER BY clause in SELECT statement. Can you put explanation of each column so that it is easy to look into issue.

Comment: yup. i need to play around with it some more.

Comment: Checking, although I'm still having problems, because the GROUP_CONCAT seems to only return arbitrary data. Not sure why though.

Comment: Provide some description of columns and tables involved so that we can look into that...

Comment: see my edit above. Let me know if you need any additional infos. THANKS!

Comment: @Shubhansh what! just order by does the trick!!! how come!!! THANKS A LOT! i was striving to find the solution of fetching unique values in GROUP_CONCAT!